# root access denied trying to change information_schema

Tags: mysql, root, privileges

I am logged in as the root user to my MySQL database (Community version 5.6). I have global privileges as I can see by executing `SHOW GRANTS;`

> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*E5BDEE3EBCA26FB68C52549E9AD22869FCE94926' WITH GRANT OPTION

However, I am trying to change a variable in the information_schema database global_variables table and getting **access denied for user root@% to database information_schema**

How can I change this value in the global_variables table?

Comment: You can't write directly to the tables in the information schema. Are you using SET ? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-statement.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`information_schema` is read-only by design. As you can read in the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-schema.html#idm140525568850752), you can't write in the table even if the user has permissions to do so.

You can change global variables by SQL query if the user has permissions:

```
SET GLOBAL <key> = <value>;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the host of the grants like this

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Host='%' WHERE Host='localhost' AND User='username';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```